# How to create Event logs for backend operations on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, logging, database

When we manually perform CRUD operations in mongo DB,how should i create event logs? As per my search i found **PROFILER** but it hamper the performance of the system. so just don't want to go with it. Is there any other options to resolve this issue?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The forthcoming 2.6 enterprise release supports [auditing](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/auditing/#auditing) which allows you to log events with filtering and a variety of options.

There is a detail page on parameters and considerations for [logging and profiling here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling). The log level can be set using this command.

```
> use admin
> db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, logLevel: 2 } )
```

You can use the --syslog option with your mongod to log your events to your host's syslog. You could also one of the many third party logging tools, such as the syslog-ng mongodb driver.

The typical practise for using profiling is to use it very minimally at strategic intervals and to turn it off when you are not using it. It offers the ability to turn it on per mongod instance which may also help performance.

A number of related backed operation concerns are discussed on the [MongoDB monitoring page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/) as well as many third party tools for operations.